# Why is $\mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{2}]$ a Unique Factorization Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Why is $\mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{2}]$ a Unique Factorization Domain?

We know that $\mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{5}]$ is not a UFD as
$$(1 + i \sqrt{5})(1 - i \sqrt{5}) = 6$$
and $6$ is also equal to $2 \times 3$.

Now $\mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{2}]$ is a UFD since $2$ is a Heegner number, however the simple factorization

$$(2 + i \sqrt{2})(2 - i \sqrt{2}) = 4 + 2 = 6 $$

which is also equal to $2 \times 3$, and therefore not unique.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Do either of your factorisations contain units?

Comment: Also don't we need to be working over the rationals in this context?

Answer (score 5):

The fallacy is that none of the four numbers
\begin{align*}
2+i\sqrt2 &= i\sqrt2 (1-i\sqrt2) \\
2-i\sqrt2 &= -i\sqrt2 (1+i\sqrt2) \\
2 &= -i\sqrt 2 (i\sqrt 2) \\
3 &= (1+i\sqrt2)(1-i\sqrt2)
\end{align*}
is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[i\sqrt2]$. Once we observe this, the error is the same as if we asserted that $14\times15=210=10\times21$ shows that $\Bbb Z$ is not a unique factorization domain.

Comment: Silly of me, exactly what I wanted pointed out. Thank you very much